# ApolloServer 2.0 context and public/private parts of the GraphQL API

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm not a pro in any way but I've started and ApolloServer/Express backend to host a site where I will have public parts and private parts for members. I am generating at JWT token in the login mutation and get's it delivered to the client.

With context I want to check if the token is set or not and based on this handle what GraphQL queries are allowed. My Express/Apollo server looks like this at the moment.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    // get the user token from the headers
    const token = (await req.headers.authorization) || '';

    if (token) {
      member = await getMember(token);
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that this locks down the GraphQL API from any queries and I want/need to reach signup/login mutations for example.

Could anyone spread some light on this to help me understand what I need to do to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i am doing it is that i will construct auth middleware even before graphql server as sometimes is needed to have information about authenticated user also in other middlewares not just GraphQL schema. Will add some codes, that you need to get it done

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (typeof req.headers.authorization !== 'string') {
    return next();
  }

  const header = req.headers.authorization;
  const token = header.replace('Bearer ', '');
  try {
    const jwtData = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    if (jwtData && jwtData.user) {
      req.user = jwtData.user;
    } else {
      console.log('Token was not authorized');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Invalid token');
  }
  return next();
};
```

This way i am injecting the user into each request if the right token is set. Then in apollo server 2 you can do it as follows.

```
const initGraphQLserver = () => {
  const graphQLConfig = {
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({
      user: req.user,
    }),
    rootValue: {},
    schema,
  };

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(graphQLConfig);
  return apolloServer;
};
```

This function will initiate ApolloServer and you will apply this middleware in the right place. We need to have auth middleware before applyin apollo server 2

```
app.use(auth);

initGraphQLserver().applyMiddleware({ app });
```

assuming the app is

```
const app = express();
```

Now you will have user from user jwtData injected into context for each resolver as "user", or in req.user in other middlewares and you can use it for example like this. This is me query for saying which user is authenticated or not

```
  me: {
    type: User,
    resolve: async (source, args, ctx) => {
      const id = get(ctx, 'user.id');

      if (!id) return null;

      const oneUser = await getOneUser({}, { id, isActive: true });
      return oneUser;
    },
  },
```

I hope that everything make sense even with fractionized code. Feel free to ask any more questions. There is definitely more complex auth, but this basic example is usually enough for simple app.

Best David

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I just eyeballed the code at the moment because Im at work at the moment but will sit down tonight and try this out :) I think I understand most of it :) Will get back with the result.

Comment: I gave it a try, but is it a lot of stuff in the context of the ApolloServer I dont need?

Not sure where every parameter to context is coming from. I do understand the auth middleware for express and that it needs to execute before the app middleware.

Comment: Hi man, sorry for the confusion, i was copying that from my project, therefore there is quite a lot additional stuff. I have removed it, so hopefully it is more clear now. Please note, that in my project i have used the schema defined with class based approach from graphql-js library not graphql-tools, threfore you have typeDefs, resolvers etc. and not the schema in apollo server constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I understand this now :)